How to find out which IIS website was affected by a w3wp app crash?
On a Windows 2019 server with a dozen classic ASP IIS websites we have one that we know is having problems. We see app crash entries in event viewer as well as report.wer files in c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_w3wp* folders that correspond to the times that users are reporting problems, but I can't find any way to definitively associate the app crash data in the report.wer (or event viewer log) to a specific website. From the report.wer file I can confirm that w3wp.exe crashed and I can find the name of the module that faulted, but I can't find anything like the app pool name or IIS site name.
How do you know IIS app pool / site the app crash data applies to?

If you open the dump file (.dmp) from that WER folder in a tool like WinDbg and run the command !peb, you will be able to see quite a lot of information about the process itself, such as APP_POOL_ID from environment variables.
That tells you which IIS application pool this worker process belonged to.

And if you are familiar with dump analysis, you can debug further to see if the root cause can be identified. Tess has many useful posts on this topic, https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/.
Most server administrators might open support cases with Microsoft via https://support.microsoft.com because the information you get (such as the faulted module) might be misleading or incomplete in many cases.

